# Is it possible to isolate docker container in user-defined overlay network from outside internet?

Tags: networking, docker, containers

With new network feature in docker 1.10 it is possible to create isolated overlay networks - which works very well. Containers in 2 separate networks can not talk to each other. Is it possible, however, to deny container in overlay network to reach public internet? Eg to make ping 8.8.8.8 fail, while having docker host connected to internet.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the `--internal` flag when creating a network with the `docker network create` command, then that network will not have outbound network access:

```
docker network  create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 mynetwork
```

I assume -- but have not tested -- that this works for overlay networks as well as for host-local networks.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the `--internal` option - that works well for local networks, but it does **not** work for the overlay. I suppose overlay network needs to connect at least to docker default dns server - and thus the flag gets ignored... In other words your example `docker network  create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 mynetwork` does not work like this `docker network  create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 --driver overlay mynetwork`