# Best practice for running a non trusted .net core application inside a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's say I want to run inside a docker container some third party .net core application I don't fully trust.

- To simplify, let's assume that application is the simple *Hello World* console app generated by `dotnet new`. This is just the 2 files **Program.cs** and **project.json**.

Right now I have tried the following approach:

- Copy that application into some folder of my host
- Create a new container using the [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) image, mounting that folder as a volume, running a specific command for building and running the app:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it --name dotnet \
               -v /some/temp/folder/app:/app \
               microsoft/dotnet:latest \
               /bin/sh -c 'cd /app && dotnet restore && dotnet run'
  ```

I was also considering the idea of having a predefined dockerfile with microsoft/dotnet as the base image. It will basically embed the application code, set it as the working dir and run the restore, build and run commands.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I could then copy the predefined dockerfile into the temp folder, build a new image just for that particular application and finally run a new container using that image.

**Is the dockerfile approach overkill for simple command line apps? What would be the best practice for running those untrusted applications?** (which might be one I completely ignore)

**EDIT**

Since I will discard the container after it runs and the docker command will be generated by some application, I will probably stay with the first option of just mounting a volume.

I have also found [this blog post](https://blog.remoteinterview.io/how-we-used-docker-to-compile-and-run-untrusted-code-2fafbffe2ad5#.yljpoyima) where they built a similar sanbox environment and ended up following the same [mounted volume approach](https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox/blob/master/API/DockerSandbox.js#L134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, what happens in docker, stays in docker.

When you link a volume (-v) to the image, the process can alter the files in the folder you mounted. But only there. The process cannot follow any symlinks or step out of the mounted folder since it's forbidden for obvious security reasons.

When you don't link anything and copy the application code into the image, it's definitely isolated.

The tcp/udp ports exposition is up to you as well as memory/cpu consumption and you can even isolate the process from internet [e.g. like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735172/is-it-possible-to-isolate-docker-container-in-user-defined-overlay-network-from)

---

Therefore, I don't think that using dockerfile is an overkill and I'd summarize it like this:

When you want to run it once, try it and forget it - use command line if you are ok with typing the nasty command. If you plan to use it more - create a Dockerfile. I don't see much space for declaring "best practice" here, considering it an question of personal preferences.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit, I meant which of those 2 options would be the best practice or approach for the scenario. I just want to spin a container so I can run the app and discard it later, so I thought creating an image might be a bit of a waste and just mounting the volume would be enough. However I don't have a great deal of experience in docker and I might be overlooking details that would rule one in favour of the other

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I'd say that it becomes an question of personal preference at this point because it technically does not make much difference. From my point of view - If you use a dockerfile, it's more isolated and you dont have to write that hell-ish command every time. You can reuse/delete the image whenever you want.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Or I'd say: If you want to run it once, try it and forget it - use command line if you are ok with typing the command. If you plan to use it more - create a dockerfile. I don't see the space for declaring "best practice" here...

Comment: That's more or less what I thought. I have also found [this blog](https://blog.remoteinterview.io/how-we-used-docker-to-compile-and-run-untrusted-code-2fafbffe2ad5#.yljpoyima) where they created a sandbox for compiling a running code and they basically just [mount the volume](https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox/blob/master/API/DockerSandbox.js#L134)

Comment: btw, could you update your answer with pretty much what you have in your last comment so I can accept it?

Comment: Agreed w/ rudolf - it's personal preference.  At the very least, I'd have that command in a batch/shell script so I don't have to type it out every time.  "I only want to run this once" is almost never true.  My personal preference is to use Dockerfiles - they're easy, repeatable.